# Text filled with inputs in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Im trying to figure out how to create a text message that has to be filled by the user by writing on text inputs.

Live example: https://www.nireleku.com/gtoys/legal/aviso-legal.html

Can this be done by any kind of plugin? I spent some hours today trying to find something but I couldnt.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I managed to do something similar, althought I'd like to find something "easier to manage" as a WordPress plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/CA5Cs/493/

Comment: Thanks you so much Haris Mustajbasic, I think that fills way better that what I did.